# Ожидание нажатия Enter

Tags: c++, linux, консоль

Как реализовать ожидание нажатия клавиши Enter. Пытался реализовать таким способом, не работает.

```
void pause(){
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
void pause(){
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1024,'\n');
    while(std::cin.get() != '\n');
    }
```

Только все равно все, что вводите - будет на экране отображаться.